# MediaWiki Upload Fails

Tags: localhost, mediawiki, mamp

I'm running an locally hosted MediaWiki, but every time I try to import the XML backup/download of my web-live MediaWiki via the Special:Import I keep getting the error `Import failed: Loss of session data. You might have been logged out. <strong>Please verify that you're still logged in and try again</strong>. If it still does not work, try [[Special:UserLogout|logging out]] and logging back in, and check that your browser allows cookies from this site.`

The suggested steps there do nothing. Any help is would be fantastic.

Comment: Do sessions work otherwise?

Comment: Does it happens after some time or immediately after you click "Import" ?

Comment: @Tgr as near as I can tell, everything else seems to work fine

Comment: @wakalaka It happens immediately, if I try to import a single page it seems to work, so I changed the upload limit to about 50% more than the file and it still happened.

Comment: On possibility that comes to mind is that your session cache and generic object cache is configured to use the same backend, and it is small enough that the imported data fills it and evicts the session.